# Cannot Login with credentials, that was used in signup form in django

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication

I have created a simple sign-up and login form for a web application. I was able to perform the sign up, but when I tried to login the user, using the credentials that I used during sign-up, it is not logging in. Only the users which are created using django- admin create superuser will be logged in, and not the users which were created using the sign up form. Here's my sample code.

## Views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            userNAME = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=userNAME, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/UserPage')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

## Urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^about/$',views.AboutPageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime), No need , displaying in home page
    url(r'^input/$',views.EmployeeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^signup/$',signup, name="signup"),
    url(r'^UserPage/$',views.UserPageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/$',auth_views.login,   {'template_name':'login.html'},name='login'),
]
```

## models.py

```
class UserCredentials(models.Model):
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_email=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user_password=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Meta:
    db_table="userdetails"

def __str__(self):
    return (self.user_name)

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=UserCredentials
        fields=['user_name', 'user_email', 'user_password']
```

And, by the way, I'm using django's default login and authenticate methods from django.contrib.auth.

Also, It would be great, if someone can explain how does django stores the data posted from the form, and where does (may be in db tables) it looks for validation, when user credentials are supplied while logging in.

Comment: you are using custom model to save the user details but in django we do have a base model auth_user which stores the info . you need to rewrite it that way

Comment: You need to use custom auth backend. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: I've got the solution, after a careful observation on the code. I'm using <UserCredentials> model to create an instance of user (basically, creating an entry in the db table for each user), where as, the URL in login.py reflects that, it should use django default < auth_login >view for login, which internally uses User model and not the UserCredentials model for validation of credentials. That's why only django-admin createsuperuser, command created users are able to authenticate.

Comment: To solve this, it is sufficient, creating a custom login view that uses the model ( UserCredentials) as a value for its model field. Anyway, Thank you for your valuable suggestions and help.